# how to fix a chart that does not show up

Tags: c#, graph, charts

I believe my codes were fine but when I start to execute the program my chart shows nothing, a black chart pops up in my windows form, there are also no errors. what my codes are trying to do is to get the date and the patientcount by daily. but hen again my chart shows nothing even the margins are gone when I execute the  system

```
string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Toshiii\Documents\Pasyente.accdb;
                         Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string strSQL = "Select count(PatientID) AS TOTAL, DateofC from 
            Patient GROUP BY DateofC";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
            OleDbDataReader dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                chart1.Series["Point"].XValueMember = "TOTAL";
                chart1.Series["Point"].YValueMembers = "DateofC";
            }
            dtr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
            conn.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO, please read [tour] [ask] and [mcve] as they are important to getting a good answer.  As it stands there is some code, but without data we cant tell if theres valid data, what it is returning vs what your code expects..  Me? Id add a shed load of debugging messages and trace whats going on

Comment: do you intend to add any data points to your chart? There should be some line like `chart1.Series["Point"].Points.AddY(...your double values here...)`

Comment: you can remove the 2 calls of `conn.Close();` and leave only the last in the `finally` section.

Comment: __Either__ use [DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) __or__ add the points from the reader as @Mong tells you. Maybe use AddXY..